# Unable to handle HTTP/404 when calling httpClient.delete() in Angular 8

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular8, angular-httpclient

I have Springboot 2.1 endpoint that returns HTTP/404 when calling DELETE method. 
There is Angular 8 application that calls that endpoint using HttpClient. It has been stripped down to simplest possible code.

If I call **httpClient.delete('url').subscribe();** while backend returns HTTP/404 I'm unable to handle errors. 
Angular throws this error in console: *ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.*

I tried handling errors as it's written in Angular http client description but it does not help. Before any error handling code is called, Angular throws error in console and no error handling is executed.

Here's the Java code

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/test")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class TestController {

  @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
  public ResponseEntity deleteObject(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
  }
}
```

Angular code calling this endpoint is:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class ObjectsService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  deleteObject() {
    return this.httpClient.delete('http://localhost:8090/api/test/5').subscribe();
  }
}
```

Chrome shows that the response is:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8090/api/test/5
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 404 
Remote Address: [::1]:8090
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Unfortunately instead of normal execution I'm getting an error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:27)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:38)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js:2476)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:465)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

edit:
There is also HTTPInterceptor that was handling errors:

```
  private handleErrors(err: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
    if (err.status === 401) {
      this.loginService.redirectToUrl = this.router.url;
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return of(err.message);
    }
  }
```

Thanks to @igor, "missing else" was spotted. Adding HTTP/404 handling in interceptor solved this problem.

Comment: So error handling like this is not called? `subscribe(() => true, () => of(true));`

Comment: If that is the case you probably have an http interceptor configured somewhere in the pipeline

Comment: @Igor spot on! I had interceptor that was able to intercept 401 but if any other error occured it returned undefined!
Thank you!

Comment: Glad you found it and more than happy to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the error handling code executing on the observable is not being reached then you have an [`HttpInterceptor`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) configured which is handling the error before this code is reached.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass argument in subscribe() that will be response. In your example

```
deleteObject() {
  return this.httpClient.delete('http://localhost:8090/api/test/5').subscribe(response => {
    // Here you will handle response
  }, (error) => {
    // Here you can handle errors
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution before and it does not help. Before error handling (second parameter to subscribe() is ever called I do get error mentioned in the question.

Comment: ` UpdateBug(id, data): Observable<Bug> {
    return this.http.put<Bug>(this.baseurl + '/bugtracking/' + id, JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.errorHandl)
    )
  }`

Create service like this then call it in deleteObject() method, it will return you Observable and you can subscribe to it and fetch response or errors.
Read more on this link --> https://www.positronx.io/angular-8-httpclient-http-tutorial-build-consume-restful-api/

Answer (score 1):

Having a generic error handler to handle the errors would be an ideal solution, if in case you need to handle errors from all the API invocations.

https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler

For more details on Error Handler and Interceptors,

[what is the difference between error handler and interceptor in angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191831/what-is-the-difference-between-error-handler-and-interceptor-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

A good start I would say is to implement interceptor and handle those errors:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

 intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   ...........
   next.handle(req)
            .pipe(tap(event => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                  // doNothing now
                }
            }))
            .pipe(catchError(err => {
                      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                          // Handle your 404 here
                          }
           }
}

}
```