# Handling error in ErrorHandler and handling in HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, exception, error-handling, angular-http-interceptors

whats is the difference between the two methods of error handling in angular 7. Do we need to handle global errors in HttpInterceptor and also in angular's inbuilt ErrorHandler. Pls let me know in HttpInterceptor what are the types of error we can handle and in ErrorHandler what errors we can handle. Do we need both or any one is enough

```html
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {  
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errMsg = '';
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // Client Side Error
          errMsg = `Client Error: ${error.error.message}`;
          console.log(error);
        }
        else {
          // Server Side Error
          errMsg = `Server Error: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
          console.log(error);
        }
        return throwError(errMsg);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```html
export class ErrorsHandler  implements ErrorHandler {

    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }   
    
    handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) {
        const notificationService = this.injector.get(NotificationService);
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            // Server or connection error happened
            if (!navigator.onLine) {
                // Handle offline error
                return notificationService.error('No Internet Connection');
            } else {
                // Handle Http Error 
                return notificationService.error(`${error.status} - ${error.message}`);
            }
        } else {
            // Handle Client Error 
            notificationService.error(error.message);    
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191831/what-is-the-difference-between-error-handler-and-interceptor-in-angular-2) that maybe is what you're looking for! :)